# Why the AudioSource.volume always 1 on play mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change the volume of sound effect of prefab through script
and no matter what the volume stay 1.

//this script attached to my prefab

```
void Start()
{
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    audio.volume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("SliderVolumeLevel",audio.volume);
    audio.Play();
    ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure its saving that to the playerPrefs?

Comment: Yes, I debug and the audio.volume get the playerPrefs value but the volume in the inspector on play mode stay 1

Comment: Well other than I added a whole bunch of code to move volume up/down/save.. works fine for me... so.. it has to be something overwriting it..